# Implements an Undo/Redo in MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, undo-redo

I have a Java application and I want to implement an Undo/Redo option. the value that I want to stock and that I want to be able to recover is an integer.

My Class `Model` implements the interface `StateEditable` and I have to redefine the 2 functions `restoreState(Hashtable<?, ?> state)` and `storeState(Hashtable<Object, Object> state)` but I don't know what to put on them. It will be really great if somebody can help me to do that.
These are the first lines of my `Model` class, the value that I want to do an undo/redo on it is `value`

```
public class Model extends Observable implements StateEditable
{
        private int value = 5;

        private UndoManager undoRedo = new UndoManager();

        final UndoableEditListener editListener = new UndoableEditListener() {
        public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent evt) {
            undoRedo.addEdit(evt.getEdit());
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Hashtable<?, ?> state)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void storeState(Hashtable<Object, Object> state)
        {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking through an [example of `StateEditable`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TheuseofStateEditable.htm), it would appear that in your `storeState` method, you need to populate the `Hashtable` that is passed in.  Similarly, you assign state in your `restoreState` from the `Hashtable` that is passed in.  You will need to define a key for the value in the `Hashtable`.  With that in mind, I suggest that you add

```
private final String KEY = "myKey";
```

to the top of your file, and then fill out the two methods like so:

```
    @Override
    public void restoreState(Hashtable<?, ?> state) 
    {
       Object val = state.get(KEY);
       if( val instanceof Integer ) //performs the null test for us.
       {
          value = val;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void storeState(Hashtable<Object, Object> state) 
    {
        state.put(KEY, value);
    }
```